# regex_replace, why does it lose the $1?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, visual-studio-2017

```
string s = " 'I'd go.' ";
s = std::regex_replace(s, std::regex("((^| )')|('($| ))"), "$1(Quotation, )");
cout << s; // '(Quotation, )I'd go.(Quotation, )
```

I want to replace the `'` with `(Quotation, )`, and I don't want to lose the original `'`. So, I use `$1` to mean the original `'`. And I don't want to replace the `'` of `I'd`.

`^` means if the `'` is at the start of the string it would be replaced.
`$` means the end of the string.

The result is supposed to be:

> '(Quotation, )I'd go.' (Quotation, )

But actually the result is

> '(Quotation, )I'd go.(Quotation, )

The left quotation replacement works fine, but the right loses the `'`. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It happens because the `'` at the end of the string is captured in Group 3:

```
((^| )')|('($| ))
|| 2 |   |
|  1   | | | 4 |
         |  3   |
```

You may refer to each of the groups with `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and `$4`, and more, you may even refer to the whole match using `$&` *replacement backreferences*.

So adding `$3` can solve the issue:

```
s = std::regex_replace(s, std::regex("((^| )')|('($| ))"), "$1$3(Quotation, )");
// =>  '(Quotation, )I'd go.' (Quotation, )
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/NQEbeX)

An alternative solution might look like

```
s = std::regex_replace(s, std::regex("(?:^|\\s)'|'(?!\\S)"), "$&(Quotation, )");
```

The `(?:^|\s)'|'(?!\S)` regex matches

- `(?:^|\s)'` - start of string or a whitespace char and a `'` after them
- `|` - or
- `'(?!\S)` - a `'` that is followed with a whitespace or end of string.

The `$&` inserts the match back into the result upon a replacement. See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NeLv6U/1) online (do not pay attention at the replacement there, the site does not support `$&` backreference).

NOTE: If you are using the latest compiler, you may use raw string literals when defining regexps, `R"((?:^|\\s)'|'(?!\\S))"`.

Comment: It works! I think I misunderstood the $1. What does it accurately mean?

Comment: Let me add more details.

Comment: oh, Your edited answer already demonstrated it. I'll carefully study it.

Comment: Great! Can't be better. $& just what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need several 'or's in your regex. Try this: `^\s*(').*(')\s*$` 
and replace the backreferences.

Comment: I tested 
^\s*(')|(')\s*$
has the same result.